# min with variable as column name

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, min

I'm currently working on a project and I'm having a problem which I can't find the answer for. So this is what I'm trying to do:

```
df
| sex      | age      | values | nationality  | 
| -------- | -------- | ------ | ------------ | 
| male     | 18       | 3      | german       | 
| male     | 40       | 4      | italian      |   
| female   | 18       | 1      | belgian      | 
| male     | 40       | 2      | american     | 


col <- "values"
groups <- c("sex", "age")

f <- function(df, col, groups) {
  df <- df |> 
    group_by_at(groups) |> 
    filter(!!col == min(col) |> 
    ungroup()
}

# Solution I want:
f(df, col, groups)

| sex      | age      | values | nationality  | 
| -------- | -------- | ------ | ------------ | 
| male     | 18       | 3      | german       |   
| female   | 18       | 1      | belgian      | 
| male     | 40       | 2      | american     |
```

The part that is giving me headaches is the use of `col` in the fucntion.
I already found the solution to use `!!col` instead of col for the first use. But I can't find the solution for `min(col)`. I already tried many things like `min(!!col)`, `min(UQ(col)` and a few others.

Thanks for your help.

Ps:
This is basically what my function should be doing, just with `sex`, `age` as a parameter (vector) and col as a parameter:

```
df <- df |>
  group_by(sex, age) |>
  filter(col == min(col)) |>
  ungroup()
```

Comment: I put the quotations only so you understand what I'm trying to do, probably its a bit confusing. And the group_by_at part isn't a typo, its the function that makes it work. With gourp_by it doesn't work, because I'm giving a vector to it  instead of 3 elements . And it doesn't work without quotations.

Comment: I want to only keep the minimum value of each group ( by age and sex), so for every group remains only 1 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach below should make your function work. To use `group_by` with an external vector of string variable names we can use `all_of()` inside `across()` inside `group_by()`.

To access the values of a variable when using a string we use `!! sym()` and we need it on both sides of the `==`.

```r
library(dplyr)

f <- function(df, col, groups) {
  df <- df %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(groups))) %>% 
    filter(!! sym(col) == min(!! sym(col))) %>%
    ungroup()
df
}

# since the original data doesn‘t use `dput()` here a test on the mtcars data
f(mtcars, "mpg", c("am", "gear"))

# A tibble: 6 x 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
3  17.8     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4
4  10.4     8  472    205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     3     4
5  10.4     8  460    215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     3     4
6  15       8  301    335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it out but it doesn't work.
Error message:
Error in `sym()`:
! Can't convert a character vector to a symbol.

Comment: Can you try again with the updated answer?

Comment: Unfortunately still the same error :/

Comment: The function runs as expected on the `mtcars` data, see the updated code above.

Comment: I'm really thankful that you're trying to help me but still with this code I get the same error message. Maybe I have the wrong dplyr version (1.0.9) ?

Comment: Interesting. I‘m on a mobile and run the code through https://rdrr.io/snippets/, and I’m not sure which version they use, but they are probably not on the latest version.

Comment: Have you restarted your session and copy pasted the code above? Although the error can be due to a differing version, I'd expect the code above to work with version 1.0.9

Comment: I now checked with dplyr version 1.0.9 and the answer above works, at least with the `mtcars` example.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the late response, but I wasn't working for the weekend. It works perfectly fine now. Thank you so much!!